# How to pass a subview to a master view in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a master view and depending on the URL and controller, it will load in another subview to a variable called `$content`, that's the idea.

Currently I am trying with:

```
return view("master")->with(["content" => view("pages.group")]);
```

So for example, if the URL is https://example.com/group/1 I am trying to get the subview included on my master template. Currently, it just gets escaped for XSS but I feel like this isn't the right way to do this?

Comment: why dont you use @include in master blade?

Comment: @user3532758 Because it could change depending on the content I wish to load

Comment: Wrap it in an `@if`? Eg: `@if(Request::segment(1) == "group")` But, do note that this method of loading based on conditions is violating loads of design patterns.

Comment: why not have `pages.group` extend `master` and define a section named `content`?

Comment: @lagbox Yes, after looking it seems like this was what I needed in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end after @lagbox mentioned it, using Laravel sections enabled me to use a master view and extend it when needed. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#extending-a-layout

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to display the sub-view content in the follwing way:

`{{ $content }}`

**Change your syntax from `{{ }}` (Escaped output) to `{!! !!}` (Non escaped output).**

`{!! $content !!}`